# GIDSignIn specify scopes before prompt

Tags: ios, google-signin, gidsignin

I upgraded to GoogleSignIn 6.0 on iOS and I can not find a way to specify scopes for login at the time of signIn. All I can see is an API called addScopes() where I can specify scopes after basic signIn. But this results in two separate prompts for signIn which is weird. Earlier, we could simply specify scopes for signIn like this:

```
  signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
  signIn.scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"]
  signIn.signIn(...)
```

I wonder if there is any sample code for new GoogleSignIn 6.0? Even the sample code supplied by Google has two step sign in, first for general signin and then add scopes sign in.

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution for your question I'm facing the same problem. thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to pull from a fork https://github.com/crspybits/GoogleSignIn-iOS

Answer (score 0):

Right now it's recommended to perform two-stage requests: sign in first, and then request permission for scopes.

```swift
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(
    with: configuration,
    presenting: presenting,
    callback: { user, error in

        // If success
        print("Sign in successfully")

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.addScopes(
            ["YOUR_SCOPE"],
            presenting: presenting,
            callback: { user, error in

                // If success
                print("Scope requested successfully")

            }
        )

    }
)
```

Reference: https://github.com/google/GoogleSignIn-iOS/issues/23#issuecomment-880233289

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s useful to note that the `addScopes` method has been removed from `GIDSignIn` instance, and moved to `GIDGoogleUser` instead. Source: https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleSignIn/changelog